# setProperty in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, file-io, properties, actionlistener

Why is `configFile.setProperty("dir", "test")` not working in the method `actionPerformed` for `ActionListener`. It won't put the property in the file.

```
settings.Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       // Check config file for first startup
       configFile = new Properties();
       try {
           configFile.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Manuals.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
       configFile.setProperty("dir", "ja");

       // Close windows
       settings.dispose();  
       interFace.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the property in the `configFile` variable, but you never write to your file.  You need to call one of the [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) store methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should call [Properties.store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) method.